# How can I relock my Xiaomi bootloader without bricking the phone?

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, bootloader, bootloader-lock

I unlocked the bootloader on my Xiaomi Mi A1, and it boots fine.

However, after I relocked it (using the top answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58410/how-to-re-lock-android-bootloader)) and rebooted, the phone flashed the white Android loading screen then went black. The same thing happens when I try to boot into recovery mode. I can still get into fastboot, though, and am able to unlock again.

How can I lock the bootloader and return to the stock Android that the phone was shipped with? I'm not worried about data loss.

Comment: https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/archive/miui/tissot

Comment: @alecxs Thanks, reinstalling Android via your link allowed me to lock the bootloader.